# Quisiera tener un image view que según una variable pudiera cambiar de imagen

Tags: java, android

El caso es que quiero reutilizar una pantalla para mostrar diferente información proveniente de un `viewList`, entonces mi objetivo es que cada elemento muestre por una imagen distinta según si he pulsado en un elemento u otro del `ListView`.

Pero ahora mismo solo se poner un imagen fija que es siempre la misma, no se si hay alguna opción de utilizar un path variable para acceder a la imagen.

Comment: Comparte el código de la pantalla/ListView con lo que hayas intentado y cómo te falla. Tal y como está ahora la pregunta, es un poco amplia.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes cambiar la imagen de un `ImageView` de diferentes formas como explica @Jorgesys en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2974902/3683321), me parece que está muy bien explicado.

Puedes utilizar los siguientes métodos para cambiar la imagen:

- [setBackgroundResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))
- [setImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
- [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

**Ejemplos:**

con [setBackgroundResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)), la imagen se pondrá como fondo:

```
myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

Mientrás que con [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)):

```
myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

y con [setImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)):

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey));
```

establecerá un Drawable como contenido del `ImageView`

**Nota:**

Con la Api 22 la función `getResources().getDrawable()` está `deprecated`. A continuación un ejemplo de cómo utilizarlo a partir de esta versión:

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
```

y de cómo validar para versiones de la API anteriores:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
   } else {
     myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.monkey);
}
```

En cuanto a mostrar una imagen dependiendo del elemento seleccionado podrías utilizar el siguiente código si tu listado es estático:

```
switch (elementoLista) {
   case 1:   myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.elem1);
             break;
   case 2:   myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.elem2);
             break;
       ....
   case n:   myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.elemn);
             break;
   default:  myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.elemdefault);
             break;
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda!